# How do I extract data from a json file and assign it to a value in a drop down menu?

Tags: json, dropdown

I have the following drop down menu and I have coordinating json files;

```
<option value="2016"> 2016 </option>
<option value="2017"> 2017 </option>
<option value="2018"> 2018 </option>
<option value="2019"> 2019 </option>
<option value="2020"> 2020 </option>
```

JNorth_Adult_Site_2016_1.geojson
JNorth_Adult_Site_2017_1.geojson
JNorth_Adult_Site_2018_1.geojson
JNorth_Adult_Site_2019_1.geojson
JNorth_Adult_Site_2020_1.geojson

What is the best way to assign the geojson files to the drop down menu. So when someone chooses 2016 on the dropdown, they will get the 2016 results?

I am very new to JS so any help will be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You're going to have to parse the FileNames and extract out the year. If they all have consistent filename length (like a mainframe file) you could use `string.SubString`. OR You might be guaranteed they all end with `_1.geojson` and you can replace that and then get the last 4 characters of each and use those values to populate your DropDownList/HtmlSelect PS you'll have to give me the Url of this Adult site, lol

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do after that. *So when someone chooses 2016 on the dropdown, they will get the 2016 results?* Javascript can't read from the FileSystem so when the user clicks on the HtmlSelect in its click event you'll need to call a function to fetch the json from an website and then render it in the page. Can you please have a read of this: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted in the comments, JS cannot directly read the file system, so I assume your webpage is hosted in server e.g. XAMPP or other alternative, and also your `geojson` files are kept in the same directory under `"files"` folder, then you can read the actual required file as you mentioned by using code something like below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="2016"> 2016 </option>
    <option value="2017"> 2017 </option>
    <option value="2018"> 2018 </option>
    <option value="2019"> 2019 </option>
    <option value="2020"> 2020 </option>
</select>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() 
    {
        //The page has been loaded and ready
        $('select').on('change', function() 
        {
            //listen to the select item changes
            $.getJSON( "files/JNorth_Adult_Site_" + $(this).val() + "_1.geojson", function( data ) 
            {
                // If year 2016 is selected file JNorth_Adult_Site_2016_1.geojson will be fetched
                // data variable contains all the content of your actual required file
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```